# When baking, the new textures don't apear like they are supposed to

Tags: texture-baking

I am making a Khopesh (egyptian sword) for my game but everytime I try to bake the materials onto a texture, blender either saves it as an internal image, makes it too dark and without the desired pattern or both. The glossmap kind of works but I am not sure if it is supposed to be like that (attached image). The maps also dont show some parts of the mesh (I think this could be linked to me using two materials). I tried the selected to active option (with a dark material plane and a copy of the sword), I tried setting up lights, I tried every button in the bake options but I am just not able to solve this problem on my own. I searched for this problem online but couldn't find any solution that fit my problem.
I hope the information is enough but it probably isn't. Sorry!
~Lavallion
[image: The Sword body nodes]
[image: The Cutting Edge nodes]
[image: Gloss map baking]
[image: I tried to bake the diffusion map here]

[The .Blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1od6qCJOCjDMxe-uyRNLbJK4weciVO1Hb)

Comment: Your screenshot are not hi-res enough to allow to check on the shader nodes. Could you add one showing only the shader nodes in fullscreen?

Comment: Sure! Here you go

Comment: OK it might not explain the baking issue but I would start redoing the shaders as it seems you are overcomplicating things with a mixing too many different yet similar shaders (diffuse mixed with emission then mix again with another emission and a principled bsdf... ). I'd start with the principled BSDF only and use its inputs to drive gloss (roughness, specular) and emission there directly.

Comment: Also keep in mind that baking gloss cannot be done directly from a material that appear glossy in Blender. It depends on the lighting setup in your scene. The way to bake gloss/roughness is via the greyscale representation of the glossy aspect of your material baked into a separate B/W image texture which can later be applied separately